# Sass/Compass compile into many locations

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I'm using Sass 3.1.10 with Compass 0.11.5. I need to compile my compass project into many diffrent locations (css_dir) due some structural reasons. Currently I compile all files for each path by hand. Is there a way to compile into many locations at the same time?

my config.rb looks like this:

```
http_path = "/"

css_dir = "skin/main/css"
#css_dir = "uc/main/css"
#css_dir = "skin/abstract/css"
#css_dir = "skin/ksv/css"

sass_dir = "sass"


images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

output_style = :compressed

preferred_syntax = :sass
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be supported out of the box. If you don't want to write a script to make the batch compiling happen, this is probably your best option: http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/browse_thread/thread/14b008b0d829ff81

Comment: yeah thanks a lot, but I think writing a little script is much more easier for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a simple shell script to compile to a given path:

```
echo "* Compiling all CSS"


echo "***** START";
cd /mainworkspace/www/

echo "***** compiling into skin1";
compass compile --time --css-dir=skin1/main/css --output-style compressed --force;

echo "***** compiling into skin2";
compass compile --time --css-dir=skin2/main/css --output-style compressed --force;

echo "***** compiling into uc skin";
compass compile --time --css-dir=uc/main/css --output-style compressed --force;


echo "***** END";
```

update:
added some params for production. Here you can find many other optional params: http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/

Comment: I know this is super old but the configuration reference has moved here: http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution with a ruby script https://stackoverflow.com/a/39635064/6440953