# Compass Source in Multiple Directories

Tags: compass-sass, sass

Have you had success compiling SASS in multiple directories?  Can you set up compass to recursively watch a directory?

I have read the documentation on add_import_path, but I would really appreciate some sample code, as I have (I am fairly certain) never written a line of ruby code.

The reason I ask is that I have several projects that share some standard scss.  I would like changes to the shared scss to cascade to all projects.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the following directroy structure:

```
project
    |-- config.rb
    +-- apps
        |-- main.scss
        |-- app1
            +-- appst1.scss
        |-- app2
            +-- appst2.scss
        +-- app3
            +-- appst3.scss
```

Then adjust your `config.rb`:

```
sass_dir = "apps"
add_import_path "apps"
...
```

and in your main.scss include the other scss files:

```
@import "app1/appst1";
@import "app2/appst2";
@import "app3/appst3";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Reto.  The question is more when you have multiple (unrelated) projects with a common scss file.


```
project1
  |-- reset.scss
  +-- project1.scss
project2
  |-- reset.scss
  +-- project2.scss
project3
  |-- reset.scss
  +-- project3.scss
```

Comment: I just posted a new answer in the aforementioned [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383716/loading-global-sass-files-in-multiple-compass-projects). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution that supports batch compass compile/watch of multiple independent SASS projects, based on two Ruby scripts.

Folder structure with the Ruby files:

```
Root
--compile.rb
--watch.rb
--Module1
----config.rb
----css
----sass
--Module2
----config.rb
----css
----sass
--Module3
----config.rb
----css
----sass
```

Run `compile.rb` and `watch.rb` with several arguments representing the paths to your module folders containing the `config.rb` files.

I.e. : `ruby compile.rb Module1/ Module2/ Module3/`

## compile.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'compass'
require 'compass/exec'

ARGV.each do |arg|
  Compass::Exec::SubCommandUI.new(["compile", arg, "--force"]).run!
end
```

I.e. : `ruby watch.rb Module1/ Module2/ Module3/`

## watch.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'compass'
require 'compass/exec'

threads = []
ARGV.each do |arg|
  threads << Thread.new {
    Compass::Exec::SubCommandUI.new(["watch", arg, "--force"]).run!
  }
  sleep(1)
end
threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```

Notice that we need to create a separate thread for each compass watch (since they are blocking processes). `sleep(1)` is necessary because `Compass::Exec::SubCommandUI` is not actually thread-safe and might run several watches on the same module, instead of one on each. In case that happens, try increasing the `sleep` value.

Create a similar `config.rb` file in all modules. You might have to use `compass init` to get the a first `config.rb` that compass recognizes.

## config.rb

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
```