# Loading global SASS files in multiple Compass projects

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'd like to create a directory of SASS files that multiple Compass projects will access. This directory would contain a number of SASS files for common elements with similar styles (form elements, clearfixes, resets, etc.) that I'd like to access and use across multiple projects.

How can I include this single global SASS folder in multiple projects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chris Eppstein, the creator of Compass, has a video describing exactly how to do that here:
https://vimeo.com/13804978

Essentially, you'll create a framework in one of your projects, and then build any future other projects (or retroactively add a line to older projects' configurations) to include that framework.

Answer (score 0):

Compass exposes this additional property called `additional_import_paths`, which accepts an Array of Strings that represents paths from where to import Sass files to your project.

I believe this is a way more straight-forward solution; I've just recently implemented on my own projects, and it works as a charm.

Hope this helps.

Here's the link for further reference:
http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/