# Compass, adding import path

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

To compile .scss files in multiple directories we need to use "add_import_path" (http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/), but i dont get how.

I've tried to add

```
additional_import_paths
add_import_path "_themes"
add_import_path = "_themes"
additional_import_paths = "_themes"
```

in my config.rb, but no luck, Compass compiling only from **sass_dir = "_modules"**

---

Update: Yes, this line

```
add_import_path "_themes"
```

doesnt gives us "no folder found" error, but compass still not compiling .scss in it

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile multiple `.scss` files you should import the "child" files into the "parent" SASS file using `@import "filename";`.

For example if you have main.scss, you might want to import more CSS from a child stylesheet called for example child.scss like this:

```
@import "_modules/child";
```

From what I understand, all that `add_import_path` does is allow you to import files from an additional directory. So you can also `@import` from `_themes/`

See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/compass-users/ayjkbqjfZ4M/CcDjdu3hmuIJ).

Answer (score 7):

There's an accepted answer here, but I don't think it answers the question, but gives an alternate solution.  Which is absolutely fine and I'm not trying to insult anyone, but what's not here is information on `add_import_path` and what it does for you.

If anyone's ever worked in Magento, you're familiar with it's fallback structure for theming and template files.  For setting up multiple stores that utilized the same default skin, we needed to include a fallback structure which would allow for changes over a pre-defined  hierarchy.  So check dis config.rb file

**myThemeA - config.rb**

```
require "font-awesome-sass"
http_path = "/skin/frontend/rwd/myThemeA/"
add_import_path "../../../rwd/default/scss"
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "../scss"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../js"
fonts_dir = "../css/fonts"
relative_assets = true

output_style = :expanded
environment = :production
sourcemap = true
```

**myThemeB - config.rb**

```
require "font-awesome-sass"
http_path = "/skin/frontend/rwd/myThemeB/"
add_import_path "../../../rwd/default/scss"
additional_import_paths = ["../../../rwd/myThemeA/scss"]
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "../scss"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../js"
fonts_dir = "../../myThemeA/css/fonts"
relative_assets = true

output_style = :expanded
environment = :production
sourcemap = true
```

So the idea here is that we have three skins and we can use import paths to only override certain files instead of including EVERY file in EVERY skin.  Which also mean, when we want to make global changes, depending on what we change, we don't have the make the change 3 times--only to where it's dependency would lay in the chain.

So...

**default** is the base of all skins

**myThemeA** is the skin by itself and uses default as it's default

**myThemeB** uses myThemeA as it's default, while myThemeA uses default as it's default.

What makes this work is the placement of `add_import_path` and `additional_import_paths`.  Essentially, it uses the `add_import_path` defined first as the default and then the subsequent `additional_import_paths` array will override what was in `add_import_path`, but anything that wasn't included in the additional, it will go look for in the default.

Hope this makes sense to anyone looking for more info on import paths.

Comment: I have noticed an import aspect of 'add_import_path' behaviour though:

If sass compilation uses a file which is found in the import path, e.g. \_framework.scss, then any imports in that file, e.g. @import "var" will then be relative to _that_ file, rather than the original folder structure that we were in. This means (using your example) that if you have a \_var.scss file in myThemeB, but you don't have a \_framework.scss file in myThemeB, then it won't use your myThemeB \_var.scss file. This is annoying, as you have to include files in a theme even though you're not changing them.

Comment: Not to go off on a tangent, but this, I believe is the advantage LESS had over SASS/SCSS.  Lazy loading deems this problem inert, because it's going to utilize the most recently loaded definition of that variable in the compilation.  I haven't played with Rudy SASS in a while.  Seems like they're moving to using CSS variables which inherently lazy load? https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2119

Comment: What Yorkshire Bear described is the exact behavior I experienced today when trying to set up a theme environment as described by Plummer and it took me a while to realize that what I am trying to achieve simply isn't possible. Is there no workaround for this?

Comment: I haven't been working in Ruby for a while, but I do something similar in Node and webpack by assigning imported packages to aliases and then overriding the alias' absolute paths via environment variables.  I hate to just drop a link at you, but this might help put you on the right track: http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-guide-environment-variables/