# LESS - similar function to Compass "add_import_path"

Tags: gruntjs, less

Coming from a Compass/Sass background.  Working on a Bootstrap/KendoUI Less project that's compiling with Grunt.

In Compass, a config option exists for "add_import"path" http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/

What it allows you to do is set a hierarchy for SASS compilation based on file structure.  So if I had a base SASS workflow/files structure that looked like this:

```
../
    /default
      style.scss
      header.scss
    /child
      header.scss
```

And I had set `/child` as the primary directory and `/default` as an import path, it would compile the SASS in `/child` and extract from `/default`only what wasn't in `/child`.  Essentially, it's a way to override files instead of editing core files.

I'm looking to replicate this process through a grunt module to avoid altering core bootstrap or kendoUI files while being able to still override them if necessary, without `!important` tags or other ugly solutions.

Comment: [`--include-path`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-include-paths)/[`path`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#paths).

Comment: Why you no make answer?  Also, will this override an entire file?  Here's an example of how add_import_path works in compass for reference.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087267/compass-adding-import-path

Comment: "Also, will this override an entire file?" - there's no such thing as "partial file override" (in either tool)... With the Less option you just set which directory has higher precedence when looking for a particular filename. I.e. if you set `--include-path: A; B; C;` the compiler will look first for the imported file in the current file dir, then (if not already found) in A, then (if not yet found) in B and so on and so on. There's no need for an overengineered separate "primary", "sub-primary", "secondary", "sub-sub-under-secondary" options hackery.

Comment: Semantics.  I wasn't looking to override partial file.  A better phrasing would have been "single file" in which, it's just going to override a single file and not the entire directory.  Instance being, `/default` contains files `A, B, C`, and `/child` contains file a slightly different `A`.  When it compiles, will it take `/child/A` and then `/default/B` and `/default/C`, or will it ignore `/default/A` and overrite/ignore `/child/A`?

Comment: "/default contains files A, B, C, and /child contains file a slightly different A." -> `--include-path: child; parent` -> profit. In other words, the order of the dirs in the option specifies the order compiler uses to look the dirs with.