# SCSS/SASS Multiple Sites in Multiple Directories

Tags: css, svn, compass-sass, sass

I'm looking at setting SCSS up on a platform that uses SVN with multiple websites on a team of eight.

Our currently site structure is like this.

```
REPO > WEBSITE1 > CSS
REPO > WEBSITE2 > CSS
REPO > WEBSITE3 > CSS
REPO > WEBSITE4 > CSS
```

Is there any way to Make Compass or SASS watch the entire repository (without having to watch / unwatch) each individual website with the config.rb or any other method?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: quora.com/Compass-stylesheet/How-to-monitor-multiple-directories-in-a-project looks like you might have to hack something if you're not using rails. Maybe try a bash script to watch each repo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535336/sass-compass-compile-into-many-locations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in repoa repob repoc repod
  do
    compass watch "$i/pathtoyourconfig.rb" &
done
```

Comment: You could also have a scripts directory in each repo where there is a script that runs sass

Comment: This looks almost perfect! Thanks tester. I would be tempted to replace the repo in the script with the site list and just reload the script for an additional repo. However I'm not sure if Sass or compass would support multiple directory watching just need to figure that out and an equivalent PC workaround and we're away!

Comment: use cygwin to run it. you can spawn separate processes by adding `&` to compass watch. like `compass watch "$i/pathtoconfig.rb" &`

Comment: Just to confirm, I tried it this morning and it's working perfectly. I have set up the main repository to have a launch file which (when it's ran) will check on every folder in that directory and check it for a CSS folder (just to confirm it's a website) and then run the watch on those folders. That way any branches should be be able to be watched just from a single click. I really appreciate the help once again!