# Compiling sass files from various Prestashop folders in Phpstorm project

Tags: compilation, sass, settings, phpstorm, prestashop

I am editing default Prestashop(1.6) theme. I am using watchers..
 How can I compile various sass files in various folder-tree level in Prestashop instalation, which i have in one phpstorm project? ([see picture](http://webintro.cz/media/sass-phpstorm-prestashop.png)).
**It works** in basic structure like: *project - project/sass - project/css*, but not in Prestashop folders structure. "Individual stylesheet must be in the sass directory".

**Is it possible to manage all sass files in various locations together in one project? Any relative settings?**

**Secondary problem**: MotoAll/modules/themeconfigurator/sass/file.sass contains: @import 'bootstrap_lib/_variables' but cant import it to file.sass because folders level? ([see the same picture](http://webintro.cz/media/sass-phpstorm-prestashop.png)).

**Thanks!**

Comment: Prestashop theme uses compass. See https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/working-with-sass-and-scss-in-compass-projects.html

Comment: Yes, I read it.. compass is instaled, allowed.. (see in picture-config.rb). Compilation works in basic structure.. but not on "larger" prestashop structure.. Jetbrains help article doesnt dealing larger structures. But maybe I got it wrong, my english isnt perfect.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't open the picture, sorry. I think you shouldn't be editing those files anyway. You should put your modified files in themes/yourtheme/sass/modules/themeconfigurator/css

Comment: Ok, I see this is a way, how to customize prestashop modules. I created file mytheme/sass/modules/mymodul/file.scss and compilation created mytheme/css/modules/mymodul/file.css. Cool, It works, Thanks! But it causes a several problems with img-paths and superior styles, but ok. Ps. Answer to various-tree-level thing can be still useful.

Comment: Possible duplicates:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688084/scss-sass-multiple-sites-in-multiple-directories or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535336/sass-compass-compile-into-many-locations or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661596/running-multiple-compass-sass-watch-operations-automatically

Comment: Im new in Phpstorm/sass/gem/npm/cmd-line thigs.. but These links solving something different or isnt relative or its not clear how, what, where :) **I need to set something like this behavior**: When I changed random .scss file in Photoshop instalation, watcher/compiller finds parent directory, where finds/create css directory and compile .css file there. Relative way settings for Phpstorm.

Comment: you can try running 'compass compile' from the folder your config.rb is located in (modify your file watcher settings accordingly) - compass will compile all project sass files then. Generated stylesheets will be placed into css_dir folder (check your config.rb)