# Is it possible to have Compass generate both expanded and compressed CSS files?

Tags: compass-sass, sass

So we've got a standard Compass CSS project, with the `sass` and `css` directories. As a scenario, let's say that the `.scss` file is called `foo-all.scss`.

Is it possible, via command line or `config.rb` or any other means, to have Compass generate **both** a `foo-all.css` file, using the "compressed" style, and also a `foo-all-debug.css` file using the "expanded" style?

It seems to me like Compass will refuse to generate a CSS file that doesn't have the exact same name as the `.scss` file, and that the most you can do is specify which directory the CSS file gets generated to.

Comment: if possible, put your debug files into another folder like /debug - there should be no problems with compiling. Maybe this is helpful in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535336/sass-compass-compile-into-many-locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like somewhat of a deficiency in Compass. Is this really an uncommon thing to do? Regardless, here's what I went with. Let's say that the folder structure is like this:

```
Rakefile
/foo
    /resources
        /css
            /debug
        /sass
            foo-all.scss
```

And then in the Rakefile, to generate both compressed and expanded version, I do this:

```
Dir.chdir "foo/resources/sass" do
    # Compile both expanded and compressed variations
    debugdir = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'foo/resources/css/debug')

    sh "compass compile --output-style compressed --force"
    sh "compass compile --output-style expanded --force --css-dir #{debugdir}"
    mv "../css/debug/foo-all.css", "../css/foo-all-debug.css"
end
```

In essence, I generate the  compressed CSS file in a separate `/debug` directory, and then move it up to the `/css` directory, to preserve URL paths in the CSS file. The `debudir` shenanigans are necessary because Compass seems to require an absolute path when using the `-css-dir` switch (on Windows, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

On my MacOS X shell I've been able to generate two different css (`production.css` and `development.css`) from a `original.scss` sass file in this way

```
fc-iMac:sass fcalderan$ sass -t compact --watch original.scss:production.css & 
                        sass -t expanded --watch original.scss:development.css
```

(I've used compact instead of compressed but the example is still valid)

Doing so, every time I make a change to `original.scss` I've got two updated css file in the same folder (with a different output style)

Of course if you have many `scss` files to watch, you could specify an entire directory to watch instead of a single file ([see SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) for further reference)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I suppose the title to my question was misleading; I really want to know how to do this same thing using **Compass**, not just SASS. Do you know of an effective way to do this with Compass, perchance?

Comment: From what I can understand in [this bug](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/507), it is not possible in Windows with just SASS, and is likely to remain that way.  You can run 2 ruby command prompts simultaneously, however.