# Get SASS to (auto) compile from specific files into different folders

Tags: node.js, express, sass, node-sass

I've got `/source/sass/skin1_settings.scss` which contains importations from `/vendors/foundation/`, some specific settings for that style and the `app.scss`. **I would like my node.JS to compile it directly into `/skin/skin1/css/app.css`, how can I do that ?**

*NB:* That's the same deal for the second style.

I'm using [node-sass-middleware](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware) in order to use node-sass with Express.

```
app.use(
 sass({
     src: [sass_folder], 
     dest: [css_folder],
     debug: true,       
 })
);
```

And here's my tree structure, thanks.

```
./    
    +--vendors/                 <-- Third-party libs from external vendors
        +--jquery/         
        +--foundation/     
        +--angularjs/      
        +--modernizr/      

    +--source/
        +--sass/                        <-- custom stylesheet (not present on the prod server)
            +--skin1_settings.scss
            +--skin2_settings.scss
            +--app.scss

    +--skin/
        +--skin1/
            +--img/             <-- imported images (..@2x, ..@3x)  
            +--css/             <-- generated stysheet

        +--skin2/
            +--img/             <-- imported images (..@2x, ..@3x)  
            +--css/             <-- generated stysheet

    +--html/                    <-- HTML Mockups
        +--...
```

Comment: You should take a look in this thread. I haven't used it myself, but I found several sites saying somewhat the same thing. Good luck! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535336/sass-compass-compile-into-many-locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make automatic compiling of SASS into CSS, the often choices are: use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/help/) or Grunt with libsass (which is node.js based), I would recommend to use that last one, you just need:

- Install [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)
- Install [libsass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-libsass) (you can also use the plugin [grunt-contrib-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-sass) )
- Setup grunt config file for the project, here you say where you want each CSS file compiled into (check the libsass page above, there are configuration samples there).

When you're going to work on the project, just use the grunt config to watch files and that's it, edit your files and grunts does the compile (you can watch for errors in the console if needed).

Hope this can help you.